# Join two SQL Queries based on first query answer

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, subquery

I have been looking everywhere and this would be the best website to ask someone for the help. I have to make SQL query that checks the total amount of bookings for the specific flight and then based on the number of bookings the system should provide the choice of an aircraft. First query works and it finds total number of bookings and i think i have the case statement right to choose an aircraft but i cant find the way of physically joining both queries , i tried to use unison , inner join and nested queries but it appears that Total number of seats booked (the answer from first query ) cannot be found please help me guys.

First SQL Query(find total number of bookings )

```
SELECT count(bookingdetails.FlightID)AS TotalNumberOfSeatsBooked,flightdetails.FlightID
FROM  bookingdetails, bookingdetails AS TEMP,flightdetails
WHERE bookingdetails.BookingID = TEMP.BookingID
AND bookingdetails.FlightID= flightdetails.FlightID
Group BY FlightID;
```

SECOND SQL Query(Choose an aircraft type depending on how many bookings are made)

```
    SELECT CASE chooseaircraft
    WHEN TotalNumberOfSeatsBooked <= 110 THEN 'BA 146-200'
    ELSE'Embraer 170'
    END AS ChoiceOfAircraft
    FROM aircrafttype;
```

Big Thanks to everyone 
After one answer i think im heading in the right direction with merging the both queries together , the code now displays the total number of seats and flight number in the sub query but the choice of aircraft column still doesnt show but it does if you run the query by it self i know i am close to getting this and i would appreciate any help to become better in SQL the code i have now is :

```
SELECT count(bookingdetails.FlightID)AS TotalNumberOfSeatsBooked,flightdetails.FlightID
FROM  bookingdetails, bookingdetails AS TEMP,flightdetails
WHERE  bookingdetails.BookingID = TEMP.BookingID
AND bookingdetails.FlightID= flightdetails.FlightID
AND bookingdetails.FlightID= flightdetails.FlightID IN(
SELECT CASE WHEN count(bookingdetails.FlightID) <= 110 THEN 'BA 146-200'
ELSE'Embraer 170' 
END AS ChoiceOfAircraft
FROM bookingdetails,flightdetails)
Group BY FlightID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same expression `count(bookingdetails.FlightID)` in your `CASE` statement (or) wrap your first query in a subquery and access the column in your outer query. That is

```
CASE WHEN count(bookingdetails.FlightID) <= 110 THEN 'BA 146-200'
ELSE'Embraer 170'
END AS ChoiceOfAircraft
```

Comment: thanks dude any idea where am i wrong on joining the queries , i have updated my code above would be great having this working for my degree project :)